# Java8 update in Google Appengine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

Working on upgrading appengine java8 sdk to the latest in standard environment.  Appengine and java target on my pom.xml is

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>

    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.90</appengine.target.version>
    <appengine-maven-plugin-version>2.4.0</appengine-maven-plugin-version>
  </properties>

<plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine-maven-plugin-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <projectId>AppID</projectId>
          <version>1</version>
          <cloudSdkVersion>342.0.0</cloudSdkVersion>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

but when i check the protopayload in the logger it is always **1.9.71** and java version is also older **1.8.0_181-google-v7**(July 2018)

Im curious to know is there an option to update latest openjdk java8 version in standard environment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In order to migrate from Java8 to the Latest version,you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences#re-packaging_a_war_file_into_a_jar_file) where it has been mentioned that :

> To migrate to the Java 11 runtime, you must re-package your App Engine
> Java 8 web application into an executable JAR file.

you can follow the migration steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences#war_migration_example).

Comment: Already aware java11 runtime at the point i don't want to move to appengine second generation because it has too many changes involved.